# VBA how are strings compared

Tags: string, vba, ms-word, compare

I am trying to figure out why two strings are not equal to each other. This is my immediate window:

```
?strg2
Table 4.662: MIMCAP Design Rules (Part 2)

?strg1
Table 4.662: MIMCAP Design Rules (Part 2)

?strg1 = strg2
False
?strg2 > strg1
True
```

Here are how my variables are determined:

```
strg1 = objSelectionChange.Text
strg1 = Replace(strg1, vbNewLine, "")
strg1 = Trim(strg1)

strg2 = objSelectionChange.Sentences(1).Text
strg2 = Replace(strg2, vbNewLine, "")
strg2 = Trim(strg2)
```

There is a subsequent `If ((Len(strg2) < 230) And (strg2 <> strg1))` test that these particular values should not be passing because they are supposed to be equal. I assumed it was some white space, so I used `Trim` and `Replace`, but the two strings are still are technically not equal for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: What does Len() return for the two? The other thing you could do is to loop each character in the original Range and list its ANSI value (the ASC function), then compare those two lists.

Comment: If you loop through all characters and you are in an international environment then I would once again favor `AscW` over `Asc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I can think of which prevent both strings to be equal:

(1) You might want to look into this the different comparison options in VBA. Look at the following for more help on that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f.aspx.

(2) If you are working internationally then `a` looks like `a` but they are in fact not the same. While the first one can be achieved with `Selection.Value = ChrW(97)` (using the latin alphabet) the second one is `Selection.Value = ChrW(1072)` (from the cyrillic keyboard). They both look (visually) the same but they are in fact different to VBA.

Note: don't try the second in the direct window as you will probably see only a `?` for ChrW(1072). Instead assign the two values (as shown above) to two different cells in a sheet and you will see that they seem the same but are in fact not:

```
Public Sub Comparison()

Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = ChrW(97)
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value = ChrW(1072)
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=$A$1=$B$2"

End Sub
```

As the final option you can compare letter by letter to find out the difference manually. The following sub will do just that (somewhat verbose):

```
Option Compare Binary

Public Sub StringCompare()
Dim strText As String
Dim strSentence As String

strText = "Table 4.662: MIMCAP Design Rules (Part 2)"      'First string to compare to.
strSentence = "Table 4.662: MIMCAP Design Rules (Part 2)"  'Second string to compare to.

Dim lngLetterCount As Long

For lngLetterCount = 1 To IIf(Len(strText) > Len(strSentence), Len(strText), Len(strSentence))
    Debug.Print "Letter " & Right("  " & lngLetterCount, 3) & ": " _
        & Mid(strText, lngLetterCount, 1) _
        & " (" & Right("00" & AscW(Mid(strText, lngLetterCount, 1)), 3) & ")" _
        & " - " _
        & Mid(strSentence, lngLetterCount, 1) _
        & " (" & Right("00" & AscW(Mid(strSentence, lngLetterCount, 1)), 3) & ") " _
        & IIf(AscW(Mid(strText, lngLetterCount, 1)) = AscW(Mid(strSentence, lngLetterCount, 1)), "", "<-- Err")
Next lngLetterCount
If Len(strText) >= lngLetterCount Then
    Debug.Print "The text string is longer than the sentence string. Ther is no match for '" & Mid(strText, lngLetterCount) & "' in sentence."
End If
If Len(strSentence) >= lngLetterCount Then
    Debug.Print "The sentence string is longer than the text string. Ther is no match for '" & Mid(strSentence, lngLetterCount) & "' in text."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: These are internal documents from the United States and the two strings are from the same document anyways. `strg1` is the selected text and `strg2` is the selected texts sentence. I compared the length as suggested by Cindy Meister and found that `strg1` is 42 characters and `strg2` is 43 characters. I am currently working on a way to find out what that extra character is with AscW